# Как расставить знаки препинания: "мои родственники брат и сестра приехали"?

Tags: приложение

1. Мои родственники - брат и сестра - приехали ко мне в гости.

"брат и сестра" - приложение.

2. Мои родственники - брат и сестра приехали ко мне в гости.

второе тире опускается, так как приложение "брат и сестра" - более конкретное значение определяемого слова "родственники".

Как правильно? Или оба рассуждения неверны?

Answer (score 2):

Приложение и уточнение не являются взаимоисключающими.

Приложение это характеристика синтаксиса: определение, выраженное существительным.

Уточнение это характеристика семантики: переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому.

В вашем предложении *брат и сестра* являются и приложением (определение выражено существительным), и уточнением (сужает понятие *родственники*).

Приложения выделяются запятыми с обеих сторон, но могут быть выделены и с помощью тире, в частности, если они несут значение уточнения:

*Мои родственники, брат и сестра, приехали ко мне в гости.*

*Мои родственники — брат и сестра — приехали ко мне в гости.*

Опустить одно из тире можно, но это происходит редко. В вашем случае приложение содержит более точное определение обобщенного понятия, что является возможной причиной опустить второе тире.

Однако, на мой взгляд, этого делать не стоит. Убрав второе тире вы размоете границы вашего приложения, и это потребует использовать контекст для его понимания:

*Мои родственники — (начало приложения) брат (конец?) и сестра (конец?) приехали ко мне в гости.*

И если в данной фразе всё кажется очевидным, то вот пример похожей структуры, в котором не всё так просто:

*Мои сотрудники — слесаря и пожарные приехали на вызов.*

С одной стороны, правила советуют не опускать второе тире перед союзом *и*, как раз для избежания таких ситуаций. С другой стороны, мы имеем дело с весьма специфическими, редкими в употреблении правилами, и нельзя исключать возможность ошибки.

Поэтому опускать тире в таких конструкциях стоит весьма осторожно.

Но, если бы у вас не было союзного сочетания, то тире смело можно опускать:

*Мои родственники — сестры приехали ко мне в гости.*